# Generating customized HTML text with fields/placeholders at several places in body

Tags: html

I am trying to send out 100 emails with HTML text body as follows :

> Hello *XYZ*, I went to your Company *X* in *PlaceY* yesterday and was
>   impressed. I want to propose to you *ProductZ*. *XYZ* would be benefited by *Productz*
>
> **Subheading in Bold** 
> Are you interested?
>
> Thanks

I want a tool where I can input XYZ, X, PlaceY and ProductZ just once and it fill it everywhere instead of having me manually edit the whole thing, and gives me an HTML content I can copy paste to my email client (Thunderbird)

Any advice on such a tool/or process

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you have a look at MaiChimp?

Answer (score 1):

using php is very easy
only need to add a PHP tags to open before the code and after de code to close it , i give you a function that can do what you want to do

```
/*  " <?PHP" <- to open the tag, and, "?>" <- to close the tag */

<?PHP function sendemail($XYZ, $X, $PlaceY, $ProductZ, $emailto)
{
$subject = "your subject here";
$body = "<html><body>Hello $XYZ, I went to your Company $X in $PlaceY yesterday and     was impressed. I want to propose to you $ProductZ. $XYZ would be benefited by $Productz <br><br><b>Subheading in Bold<b><br> Are you interested?<br><br>Thanks</body></html>";          

    $headers = "From: fromemail@yourdomain.com \r\n" ;
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    "X-Mailer: php";
    if (mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) 
    {
     return 1;
    }
} ?>
```